# One-Sample Log-rank test statistic

Tags: logrank-test

Ok, I am totally confused, this is probably a pure math rather than a statistic question but please enlighten me.

I found the logrank statistic formula being reported in the literature in 2 ways, but I am not sure which one is correct. When I plug the same number in both formula, i get different results for the chi-square.

Which one should I use?

$O$ = total of observed events

$E$ = total of expected events

1. $$\frac{(O-E)^2}{E} $$
2. $$\frac{O-E}{\sqrt{E}}$$

Which one should be used? The main reason I am asking is because when I apply the weights (W) as in the formula below, it looks like the weights are being cancelled out:

[image: one-sample logrank statistic]

Comment: That zero in #1 ('0') is meant to be an 'O' as in observed events, right?

Comment: yes, sorry my bad, edited

Comment: I think both are correct.

Comment: The first thing you mention is simply the square of the second. Neither is exactly a log rank statistic, since that would involve some kind of sum of terms. Compare your second proposal with the statistic [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-rank_test) for example and note several differences.

Comment: O and E are sums. Sorry my bad.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just read this paragraph from the same page of your book and remember that square of a standard normal distribution is a chi-square distribution. Therefore the two tests are equivalent. You can use any of them.

Comment: I understand that. However I don't understand how the weights (W) don't cancel out in either of these 2 formulae. How can we apply weights when they cancel out in both numerator and denominator?Also another thing that confuses me (from the same page of the book): "a weight function is the weight W(t) = Y(t) which yields the one-sample log-rank test". So the one-sample logrank test is  using Gehan weight by design? Am I missing something here? :S

Comment: Do you mean you try to cancel W for this ratio $\frac{\left \{  \sum_i^DW(t_i)\frac{d_i}{Y(t_i)}-\int_{0}^{r}W(s)b_0(s)ds \right \}^2}{\int_{0}^{r}W^2(s)\frac{b_0(s)}{y(s)}ds}$ ?W is a function or a random variable, I don't understand how you cancel them out? Now, i even don't know how to show it is a $\chi^2$ distribution.

Comment: Doesn't the above formula simplify to W * (Σ(Observed) - Σ(Expected)) / (W * Var() )  ?

Comment: No, I think  $\int_{0}^{r}W^2(s)\frac{b_0(s)}{Y(s)}ds$ itself is the variance when the Expected value $ E(W(s))$ is zero. Also,  do you remember the definition of variance is $E(X^2)-[E(X)]^2$ and $E(X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2f(x)dx$ this is exactly the same when E(X)=0.  I think you cannot factor out W here. It is not a constant, it is a random variable(function).

Comment: Ok, so if I have observed deaths per year and Expected deaths per year, how do I calculate a weighted one-sample logrank test? I don't have the h0 so I cannot use the formula in the picture. All i know is that Var = sum of Expected.

Comment: I did not study the book, although the formulas seem not  difficult. In practice, I think this paper may help. http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC403858/

Comment: I read this article, it is very basic and doesn't cover what I am asking however.